# Minimum Working Example for ajax POST in Laravel 5.3

Tags: ajax, laravel, post

Can someone please explain the ajax post method in Laravel 5.3 with a full-working minimum example?
I know there are some resources in the web, but I miss a concise, straight-forward minimum example.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I presume you have a basic understanding of the model-controler-view paradigm, a basic understanding of Laravel and a basic understanding of JavaScript and JQuery (which I will use for reasons of simplicity).

We will create an edit field and a button which posts to the server. (This works for all versions from Laravel 5.0 to 5.6)

## 1. The Routes

At first you need to add routes to your *routes/web.php*. Create one route for the view, just as you know from ordinary views:

```
Route::get('ajax', function(){ return view('ajax'); });
```

The second route you need to create is the route that handles the ajax post request. Take notice that it is using the **post** method:

```
Route::post('/postajax','AjaxController@post');
```

## 2. The Controller Function

In the (second) route you created just now, the Controller function *post* in the *AjaxController* is called. So create the Controller

```
php artisan make:controller AjaxController
```

and in the *app/Http/Controllers/AjaxController.php* add the function *post* containing the following lines:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class AjaxController extends Controller {

   public function post(Request $request){
      $response = array(
          'status' => 'success',
          'msg' => $request->message,
      );
      return response()->json($response); 
   }
}
```

The function is ready to receive data via a Http request and returns a json-formatted response (which consists of the status 'success' and the message the function got from the request).

## 3. The View

In the first step we defined the route pointing to the view *ajax*, so now create the view *ajax.blade.php*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- load jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- provide the csrf token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $(".postbutton").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    /* the route pointing to the post function */
                    url: '/postajax',
                    type: 'POST',
                    /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
                    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message:$(".getinfo").val()},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                    success: function (data) { 
                        $(".writeinfo").append(data.msg); 
                    }
                }); 
            });
       });    
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <input class="getinfo"></input>
    <button class="postbutton">Post via ajax!</button>
    <div class="writeinfo"></div>   
</body>

</html>
```

If you wonder what's the matter with this csrf-token, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf