# Process result from jquery form

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, request

how can I process an output from this [form](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-append-and-remove-table-row-dynamically)?
Working in Laravel and I am familiar with `Input::get('name')` but I am not familiar with jquery and processing of such forms which can have variable number of rows.

I tried `<input type="text" id="name" name=name[] placeholder="Name">` and then

```
foreach (Input::get('name') as $value){
 // code logic 
}
```

but with no luck

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this out [Minimum Working Example for ajax POST in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981922/minimum-working-example-for-ajax-post-in-laravel-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach (Input::get('name') as $value){
// code logic 
}
```

or

```
foreach ($request->input('name') as $value){
// code logic 
}
```

or

```
foreach (request('name') as $value){
// code logic 
}
```

Comment: I will get just the last value I entered. Say I have 10 names I will get only the last one as a result. I assume the problem is with <input type="text" id="name" name=name[] placeholder="Name">

Answer (score -1):

If you do have an input in a form like

```
<input type="text" id="name" name=name[] placeholder="Name">
```

then you could use the following jquery to get the current value of the input

```
$('input[name="name[]"]').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

**explanation:**

```
$('input[name="name[]"]')
```

this gets every 'input' with the name 'name[]'

```
.each(function(){
```

this loops over the previously found inputs

```
console.log( $(this).val() );
```

this shows the value of the current input from the loop in the console (press f12 to show dev tools in browser)
replace piece of code with whatever you want

**see also**

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

https://api.jquery.com/each/

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp

Comment: It is always better to include some sort of explanation than just giving a code block. A plus would be also including a reference.

Comment: Better to give details description so that everyone can understand. Or otherwise just give it as a  comment.

Comment: Consider adding a little description, which explain how the code works.