# Bootstrap Toggle to Update Database in Laravel 5

Tags: ajax, web, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So i'm trying to update a user status to either enabled or disabled in the user database. I already have my toggle in place. When i view the user table from the dashboard, i want to be able to see the toggle button according to their status. I also want to be able to update their status using the same toggle.

I know it can be done with AJAX but i'm not sure about the implementation.

Anyone kind enough to enlighten me?

Comment: In your route and controller declare and manipulate code as you would on a normal form POST and then run your AJAX. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981922/minimum-working-example-for-ajax-post-in-laravel-5-3

Answer (score 0):

You are right!
You should implement it with ajax.
Firstly create a route and controller method for accessing/controlling data. Then, implement ajax call. You can use axios library for this,too. It is a very powerful library. After you send ajax call and take the response, You should manipulate DOM according to ajax response. It is a generic question and generic answer :)