# How to send data from ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to transfer data to the controller using ajax. Here is the ajax code

```
$(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/insert_",
        type:"post",
        data:{
            name2:"admin",
            _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
        }
     })
});
```

Here is the code in the controller

```
public function insert_db(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Here is the layout code

```
<form action="/insert_" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" id="bt1" value="do it">
</form>
```

Here is code в web.php

```
Route::post('/insert_',"StudentController@insert_db");
```

Displays this
[image]
Why does display this? Please help

Comment: change ur name2 become 'name2'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum Working Example for ajax POST in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981922/minimum-working-example-for-ajax-post-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is running at all? Looks like you're just posting the form from the html instead of through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery ajax request should look like below:

```
$(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/insert_",
        type:"post",
        data:{
             "name":"test",
            _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
        }
     })
});
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{

    var payload = JSON.stringify({
                  'name': 'test',
                  '_token': $("input[name='_token']").val()
                });

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/insert_",
        type:"post",
        data:payload
     })
});
```

Comment: i changed, but how to display variable "name2" in controller?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but i will love to get the string part by coding it like this

```
 $(document).on("click", '#bt1', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/insert_",
        type:"post",
        data:{
            "name2":"admin",
            _token: $("input[name='_token']").val()
        }
     })
});
```

noticed that i changed name2:"admin" to "name2":"admin"

Comment: i changed, but how to display variable "name2" in controller?

Comment: use $request->name2

Comment: displays error. May be problem in location js file?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? is it that you want to access the return value in the ajax call?

Comment: Yes, i want to get variable from ajax to controller

Comment: getting variable from ajax to controller, $name2=$request->name2, while sending the name2 back to ajax call, you will do, return response()->json(['name2'=>$name2]);