# internal server error using Laravel and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am a beginner with js and ajax and I was trying to do some basic tutorials on ajax on a brand new Laravel project on a Wamp local server.

I got an internal server error 500 everytime I tried and I am a bit at a loss after checking again and again the route or the token.

For reference, I used the basic example on this link [Minimum Working Example for ajax POST in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981922/minimum-working-example-for-ajax-post-in-laravel-5-3)

Can someone offer some guidance on what I should check?

Thank you

Edit : my mistake: I did not pay attention to the syntax in my controller and that was my mistake. Many thanks to Felipe Duarte who told me to look at the laravel.log. The error was on line 1.

Laravel. log

```
#29 C:\wamp64\www\laravel_test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))

#30 C:\wamp64\www\laravel_test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\wamp64\www\laravel_test\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 {main}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('ajax', function(){ return view('ajax'); });
Route::post('/postajax','AjaxController@post');
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $request){
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => $request->message,
        );
        return response()->json($response); //
}
```

The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- load jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- provide the csrf token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $(".postbutton").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    /* the route pointing to the post function */
                    url: 'postajax',
                    type: 'POST',
                    /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
                    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message:$(".getinfo").val()},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                    success: function (data) { 
                        $(".writeinfo").append(data.msg); 
                    }
                }); 
            });
       });    
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <input class="getinfo"></input>
    <button class="postbutton">Post via ajax!</button>
    <div class="writeinfo"></div>   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's the error? Look at `storage/logs/laravel.log` or apache error_log

Comment: I updated my post with what I got from the log

Comment: See that line that starts with `#29`? Means line 29 of the stack error. Update your question with all lines of this error and the error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Felippe. Thanks to you I found the mistake. I forgot a } in the controller. I am such a noob.

Comment: No problem, always go for error log first. Usually is a simple thing. Good luck.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i should ask the same first before guessing, thank you for inspiring me :) and KarmaWin you can use my answer as a reference then, good luck

Answer (score 0):

here :

```
Route::get('ajax', function(){ return view('ajax'); });
Route::post('/postajax','AjaxController@post'); //you can add name to this route
```

you can replace _token in ajax data to HTTP headers, put this before ajax()

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
  }
});
```

then your ajax should be :

```
$.ajax({
  /* the route pointing to the post function */
  url: 'postajax', // change to url('/postajax') or with route_name route('route_name') in blade format
  type: 'POST',
  /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
  data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message:$(".getinfo").val()},
  dataType: 'JSON',
  /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
  success: function (data) { 
    $(".writeinfo").append(data.msg); 
  }
});
```