# How to keep page editable during file uploads (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, forms, file-upload

I work on a Saas project where users can submit/upload items.
I want to create a similar work-flow like Youtube.
This means that the user uploads image file, ZIP files etc. which then show in the upload progress block, during this time I want the user to be able to edit the other informations like tags, text description, price for item etc.

At Youtube a user can upload a video file and edit all other things during the upload, he can even leave the page and the upload continues in the background.

But in my project whenever a user uploads a file these fields can not be edited properly or get removed again after the upload is successful.
Please point me to a solution how this works/how Youtube et al approached this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do this with javascript features
Like sending a file with `ajax` in laravel and php.
By doing this, you can still access the elements inside your web page.

Comment: shahkajeh

Thank you. Can you point me towards an example on the internet?

At Youtube I can even leave the page and come back and the upload continues.

Thanks.

Comment: this link can helful 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981922/minimum-working-example-for-ajax-post-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: The ajax solution is already implemented but sometimes other elements which have been edited during upload (checkboxes) get unchecked again when the upload is completing 100%. So I wondered how this can be prevented.